# Why my /etc/hosts file is empty in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, server, localhost, hostname, hosts

In Ubuntu my /etc/hosts file is empty. It happened suddenly, i did not modify it and don't think any other program also modified it. How can this happen ?

Now moreover I am not able to edit the /etc/hosts file from vi. I tried changing permission using `sudo` but that did not work as sudo was giving me 'unable to resolve host ghost' error. ghost is my host name. One more thing I have noticed while installing Ubuntu I set computer name as 'GHOST' which was taken as the hostname. Now if I change it to anything like 'ABC' the hostname it takes is 'abc' (all in lowercase) also if the device name is like abc.xyz.com then the hostname it takes is abc-xyz-com, replaces all . with - . Why this is happening.

Moreover how should I recover my /etc/hosts file as I am not able to edit the file at all.

Comment: Did you try `hostnamectl set-hostname NEWNAME`?

Comment: this only changes the hostname right ? how does it affect /etc/hosts ?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `/etc/hosts` file...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type the following...

  - `mount -o rw,remount /` # remount the disk r/w
  - `vi /etc/hosts` # use any editor you like
  - minimum hosts file should look something like...

/etc/hosts...

```
127.0.0.1   abc.local   abc  localhost
127.0.1.1   abc
```

Reboot the computer.